# Ruby on Rails: Accessing public javascripts from pages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, routes, public

I'm having a problem accessing my javascripts from certain pages in my local Ruby on Rails site.

I have jquery javascript files located in /public/javascripts
These scripts render an instagram feed that is embed in the page

When I go to a page like `http://localhost:3000/users`, the script loads fine; however, if I go to a particular user,  `http://localhost:3000/users/1`, the script does not load.

I feel like I am missing some kind of fundamental routing technique.

The scripts are located in my `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

They are referenced like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Add a / infront of the src i.e. src="/javascripts/jquery-1.6.1.mins.js"

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? It makes a difference.

Comment: the '/' did it.  So simple, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the absolute path of jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

Or you could include the below line in the `application.js` if your rails is not old enough.

```
//= require jquery
```